# angular2 Only support at most 9 interpolation values

Tags: angular

When I am trying to interpolate more than 9 properties of an object in template I am getting the following error:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Only support at most 9 interpolation values!

The issue could be reproduced at : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/3M7lw6U4RAuOPacM4rmj?p=preview

```
<ul>
    <li 
      *ngFor="let lead of leads"
    >
       {{lead.first_name}} {{lead.last_name}} 
        {{lead.primary_email}}  {{lead.primary_phone}}
         {{lead.primary_address_line_1}}  {{lead.primary_address_line_2}}  {{lead.primary_address_city}}  {{lead.primary_address_state}}  {{lead.primary_address_zip}}  {{lead.date_of_birth}}
       <input type="checkbox" [checked]="lead.is_pre_approved" (change)="toggleAttending.emit(lead)" />
       <button (click)="removePerson.emit(lead)">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Expected/desired behavior
It should be able to print any number of properties of an object

Comment: Is it? Really? I wonder.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser.ts#L222 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/linker/view_utils.ts#L91

Answer (score 5):

I think this is not an issue, just a way to prevent the parser runs out of memory, but is important to highlight that this limitation is **per each html element**, you can tweak your template wrapping your interpolation expressions in an  element as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let lead of leads">
        <div>
            {{lead.first_name}} {{lead.last_name}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{lead.primary_email}} {{lead.primary_phone}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{lead.primary_address_line_1}} {{lead.primary_address_line_2}} {{lead.primary_address_city}} {{lead.primary_address_state}}
            {{lead.primary_address_zip}} {{lead.date_of_birth}}
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="lead.is_pre_approved" (change)="toggleAttending.emit(lead)" />
        <button (click)="removePerson.emit(lead)">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```